# program crashes when i use push_back() function

Tags: c++

I'm learning a game tutorial and I got a problem, here is the code:

**in .h file**

```
std::vector<GameObject*> m_gameObjects;
GameObject* a;
```

**in .cpp file**

```
GameObject* player = new Player;
m_gameObjects.push_back(player);
a=player;
```

This part of the code passes the pointer `player` to anther function that updates the screen so when I click on a play button on the screen a sprite appears

like this

```
m_gameObjects[i]->update();
```

or

```
a->update();
```

The problem is when I use `m_gameObjects.push_back(player)` the program crashes, when I remove this line and use `a->update()` it works.

Comment: m_gameObjects is a class (not a pointer), so m_gameObjects->update() should not compile.

Comment: @RealProgrammer57 I guess he is missing some `[i]`... Then it would make sense

Comment: @RealProgrammer57 Please keep your terminology correct; `m_gameObjects` is *not* a class, rather an object (`std::vector<GameObject*>` is the class/type).

Comment: Don't use vectors of naked pointers unless you have a really good reason. That said, the bug is almost certainly in code we can't see -- it's almost impossible to use standard containers of naked pointers correctly.

Comment: @Qix You are right, it is an instance of a class. My bad.

Comment: The error is absolutely happening in code that you have not shown. Have you tried compiling in debug and running under GDB? We need more information to solve this.

Comment: My crystal ball says rule of three problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that push_back moves pointer to the object into vector and replace the source with nullptr. Try to rewrite that using standard smart pointers

in .h file

```
#include <memory>

typedef std::shared_ptr<GameObject> GameObjectType;
std::vector<GameObjectType> m_gameObjects;
GameObjectType a;
```

in .cpp file

```
GameObjectType player(new Player);
m_gameObjects.push_back(player);
a=player;
```

You can also use make_shared() to make a shared copy or std::weak_ptr for unreliable pointer.